# Empty Sencha Touch 2 List

Tags: sencha-touch-2

**[The Git Ropo for full code](https://github.com/jiewmeng/-scraps--Learning-Sencha-Touch-2)**

I have defined:

/app/model/Todo:

```
Ext.define('Test.model.Todo', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'priority', type: 'integer', defaultValue: 0 },
            { name: 'done', type: 'boolean' }
        ]
    }
});
```

/app/store/TodoStore

```
Ext.define('Test.store.TodoStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [ 'Test.model.Todo' ],
    config: {
        model: 'Test.model.Todo',
        data: [
            { title: 'Todo Item 1', priority: 0, done: false },
            { title: 'Todo Item 2', priority: 0, done: false },
            { title: 'Todo Item 3', priority: 0, done: false },
            { title: 'Todo Item 4', priority: 0, done: false },
            { title: 'Todo Item 5', priority: 0, done: false },
            { title: 'Todo Item 6', priority: 0, done: false }
        ]
    }
});
```

Now, if I just use `store: 'TodoStore'` in a list, I get

> [WARN][Ext.dataview.List#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found

So I added too app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Test',
    ...
    stores: [ 'TodoStore' ],
```

The warning goes away, but I still have a blank list. Am I missing something?

---

**Old Post below**

```
Ext.define("SimpleTodo.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: [ 'Ext.TitleBar', 'Ext.dataview.List' ],
    config: {
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        items: [
            ...
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl: '{name}',
                store: {
                    fields: ['name'],
                    data: [
                        { name: 'Todo 1' },
                        { name: 'Todo 2' },
                        { name: 'Todo 3' },
                        { name: 'Todo 4' },
                        { name: 'Todo 5' },
                        { name: 'Todo 6' }
                    ]
                }

            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Getting:

> Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got `#<Object>`

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Don't get any errors, but the list view is empty. Tried inline store, proper store, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Sencha Touch does not understand the way you've defined your store.

You should do something like this, which consists of 3 steps:

Defining model

```
Ext.define('SimpleTodo.model.listitem',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        ],
    }
})
```

Defining store:

```
Ext.define('SimpleTodo.store.listitems', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'SimpleTodo.model.listitem',
        data: [
             { name: 'Todo 1' },
                        { name: 'Todo 2' },
                        { name: 'Todo 3' },
                        { name: 'Todo 4' },
                        { name: 'Todo 5' },
                        { name: 'Todo 6' }
        ],
    }
});
```

finally, in your list:

```
store: 'listitems'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, do I need to name the store somewhere? Or add an id?

Comment: `SimpleTodo.store.listitems` is the class name of your store, and when you add it as config, simply use `listitems` as I've written above. There's no need to add an id to your store.

Comment: FYI, I updated my original post, fixed the original problem, but I still get an empty list

Comment: did you add `models: ['listitem']` to your app config yet?

Comment: I have updated my OP with the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jiewmeng/-scraps--Learning-Sencha-Touch-2). No errors now but its still an empty list

Comment: please upload your full source code to sencha fiddle, because it's able to debug live. Sorry for my laziness. xD

Comment: Didnt know theres such a thing. But here it is [link](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#IiA8y), hope I put everything in the right places (will be great if there was an upload instead of copy file by file)

Comment: I will work on this and notify you when a working solution is available :)

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, you can't define a list within a panel (however, this view could be part of a tabpanel). So:

```
Ext.define("SimpleTodo.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    config: {
        title: 'Simple Todo',
        itemTpl: '{name}',
        store: 'myStore'
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here's an example of a list in a container with a titlebar. Note the `layout: 'vbox'` on the container and the `flex: 1` on the list. Those are both necessary for the list to display properly.

```
Ext.define("SimpleTodo.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    config: {
        layout: 'vbox',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Simple ToDo'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'listcmp',
                flex: 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With a separate view containing your list definition. E.g:

```
Ext.define('SimpleTodo.view.ListCmp', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'listcmp',

    config: {
        store: 'SimpleToDo',
        itemTpl: '{title}'
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get my title bar in then? Also if I use a tab panel I will have a tab bar right? I dont want a tab bar, just something with a title bar and list

Comment: Try putting the titlebar & list into Ext.Container rather than Ext.Panel. I don't know how the rest of your app is structured, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

try supplying full class path of the store:

```
store: 'SimpleTodo.store.listitems',
```

I suppose the framework does not know what class you are referring by just the class/file name.

if still not working i will suspect the list does not what to display, so try configuring the list itemTpl config:

```
itemTpl: '{name}',
```